# Create a sublist by datedelta in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of data points that contains a measurement every 5 minutes for 24 hours. I need to create a new list with the average of that measurement for each hour in the list. What's the best way to accomplish that?

```
Date                          Amount
2015-03-14T00:00:00.000-04:00 12545.869 
2015-03-14T00:05:00.000-04:00 12467.326
2015-03-14T00:10:00.000-04:00 12416.948
2015-03-14T00:15:00.000-04:00 12315.698
2015-03-14T00:20:00.000-04:00 12276.38
2015-03-14T00:25:00.000-04:00 12498.696
2015-03-14T00:30:00.000-04:00 12426.145
2015-03-14T00:35:00.000-04:00 12368.659
2015-03-14T00:40:00.000-04:00 12322.785
2015-03-14T00:45:00.000-04:00 12292.719
2015-03-14T00:50:00.000-04:00 12257.965
2015-03-14T00:55:00.000-04:00 12221.375
2015-03-14T01:00:00.000-04:00 12393.725
2015-03-14T01:05:00.000-04:00 12366.674
2015-03-14T01:10:00.000-04:00 12378.578
2015-03-14T01:15:00.000-04:00 12340.754
2015-03-14T01:20:00.000-04:00 12288.511
2015-03-14T01:25:00.000-04:00 12266.136
2015-03-14T01:30:00.000-04:00 12236.639
2015-03-14T01:35:00.000-04:00 12181.668
2015-03-14T01:40:00.000-04:00 12171.992
2015-03-14T01:45:00.000-04:00 12164.298
2015-03-14T01:50:00.000-04:00 12137.282
2015-03-14T01:55:00.000-04:00 12116.486
2015-03-14T02:00:02.000-04:00 12090.439
2015-03-14T02:05:00.000-04:00 12085.924
2015-03-14T02:10:00.000-04:00 12034.78
2015-03-14T02:15:00.000-04:00 12037.367
2015-03-14T02:20:00.000-04:00 12006.649
2015-03-14T02:25:00.000-04:00 11985.588
2015-03-14T02:30:00.000-04:00 11999.41
2015-03-14T02:35:00.000-04:00 11943.121
2015-03-14T02:40:00.000-04:00 11934.346
2015-03-14T02:45:00.000-04:00 11928.568
2015-03-14T02:50:00.000-04:00 11918.63
2015-03-14T02:55:00.000-04:00 11885.698
2015-03-14T03:00:00.000-04:00 11863.065
2015-03-14T03:05:00.000-04:00 11883.256
2015-03-14T03:10:00.000-04:00 11870.095
2015-03-14T03:15:00.000-04:00 11849.104
2015-03-14T03:20:00.000-04:00 11849.18
2015-03-14T03:25:00.000-04:00 11834.229
2015-03-14T03:30:00.000-04:00 11826.603
2015-03-14T03:35:00.000-04:00 11823.516
2015-03-14T03:40:00.000-04:00 11849.386
2015-03-14T03:45:00.000-04:00 11832.385
2015-03-14T03:50:00.000-04:00 11847.059
2015-03-14T03:55:00.000-04:00 11831.807
2015-03-14T04:00:00.000-04:00 11844.027
2015-03-14T04:05:00.000-04:00 11873.114
2015-03-14T04:10:00.000-04:00 11904.105
2015-03-14T04:15:00.000-04:00 11879.018
2015-03-14T04:20:00.000-04:00 11899.658
2015-03-14T04:25:00.000-04:00 11887.808
2015-03-14T04:30:00.000-04:00 11879.875
2015-03-14T04:35:00.000-04:00 11924.149
2015-03-14T04:40:00.000-04:00 11929.499
2015-03-14T04:45:00.000-04:00 11932.086
2015-03-14T04:50:00.000-04:00 11989.847
2015-03-14T04:55:00.000-04:00 12000.971
```

Comment: Instead of parsing the date string and grouping that way, it looks like you could just use a prefix substring since you're grouping by hours -- it would be much easier and faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a beautiful use of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) because you can actually take advantage of the generators it returns instead of instantly making them lists or something:

```
import itertools, pprint

d = {}
for (key,gen) in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda l: int(l[0][11:13])):
    d[key] = sum(v for (d,v) in gen)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

And for *average* instead of *sum*:

```
import itertools, pprint

def avg(gf):
    _sum = 0
    for (i,e) in enumerate(gf): _sum += e
    return float(_sum) / (i+1)

d = {}
for (key,gen) in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda l: int(l[0][11:13])):
    #d[key] = sum(v for (d,v) in gen)
    d[key] = avg(v for (d,v) in gen)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: 148410.565,
 1: 147042.743,
 2: 143850.52000000002,
 3: 142159.685,
 4: 142944.15699999998}
```

Where the key of the dictionary (`[0,1,2,3,4]`) corresponds to the hour of the timestamp.

Input:

```
lst = [
    ['2015-03-14T00:00:00.000-04:00', 12545.869 ],
    ['2015-03-14T00:05:00.000-04:00', 12467.326],
    ['2015-03-14T00:10:00.000-04:00', 12416.948],
    ['2015-03-14T00:15:00.000-04:00', 12315.698],
    ['2015-03-14T00:20:00.000-04:00', 12276.38],
    ['2015-03-14T00:25:00.000-04:00', 12498.696],
    ['2015-03-14T00:30:00.000-04:00', 12426.145],
    ['2015-03-14T00:35:00.000-04:00', 12368.659],
    ['2015-03-14T00:40:00.000-04:00', 12322.785],
    ['2015-03-14T00:45:00.000-04:00', 12292.719],
    ['2015-03-14T00:50:00.000-04:00', 12257.965],
    ['2015-03-14T00:55:00.000-04:00', 12221.375],
    ['2015-03-14T01:00:00.000-04:00', 12393.725],
    ['2015-03-14T01:05:00.000-04:00', 12366.674],
    ['2015-03-14T01:10:00.000-04:00', 12378.578],
    ['2015-03-14T01:15:00.000-04:00', 12340.754],
    ['2015-03-14T01:20:00.000-04:00', 12288.511],
    ['2015-03-14T01:25:00.000-04:00', 12266.136],
    ['2015-03-14T01:30:00.000-04:00', 12236.639],
    ['2015-03-14T01:35:00.000-04:00', 12181.668],
    ['2015-03-14T01:40:00.000-04:00', 12171.992],
    ['2015-03-14T01:45:00.000-04:00', 12164.298],
    ['2015-03-14T01:50:00.000-04:00', 12137.282],
    ['2015-03-14T01:55:00.000-04:00', 12116.486],
    ['2015-03-14T02:00:02.000-04:00', 12090.439],
    ['2015-03-14T02:05:00.000-04:00', 12085.924],
    ['2015-03-14T02:10:00.000-04:00', 12034.78],
    ['2015-03-14T02:15:00.000-04:00', 12037.367],
    ['2015-03-14T02:20:00.000-04:00', 12006.649],
    ['2015-03-14T02:25:00.000-04:00', 11985.588],
    ['2015-03-14T02:30:00.000-04:00', 11999.41],
    ['2015-03-14T02:35:00.000-04:00', 11943.121],
    ['2015-03-14T02:40:00.000-04:00', 11934.346],
    ['2015-03-14T02:45:00.000-04:00', 11928.568],
    ['2015-03-14T02:50:00.000-04:00', 11918.63],
    ['2015-03-14T02:55:00.000-04:00', 11885.698],
    ['2015-03-14T03:00:00.000-04:00', 11863.065],
    ['2015-03-14T03:05:00.000-04:00', 11883.256],
    ['2015-03-14T03:10:00.000-04:00', 11870.095],
    ['2015-03-14T03:15:00.000-04:00', 11849.104],
    ['2015-03-14T03:20:00.000-04:00', 11849.18],
    ['2015-03-14T03:25:00.000-04:00', 11834.229],
    ['2015-03-14T03:30:00.000-04:00', 11826.603],
    ['2015-03-14T03:35:00.000-04:00', 11823.516],
    ['2015-03-14T03:40:00.000-04:00', 11849.386],
    ['2015-03-14T03:45:00.000-04:00', 11832.385],
    ['2015-03-14T03:50:00.000-04:00', 11847.059],
    ['2015-03-14T03:55:00.000-04:00', 11831.807],
    ['2015-03-14T04:00:00.000-04:00', 11844.027],
    ['2015-03-14T04:05:00.000-04:00', 11873.114],
    ['2015-03-14T04:10:00.000-04:00', 11904.105],
    ['2015-03-14T04:15:00.000-04:00', 11879.018],
    ['2015-03-14T04:20:00.000-04:00', 11899.658],
    ['2015-03-14T04:25:00.000-04:00', 11887.808],
    ['2015-03-14T04:30:00.000-04:00', 11879.875],
    ['2015-03-14T04:35:00.000-04:00', 11924.149],
    ['2015-03-14T04:40:00.000-04:00', 11929.499],
    ['2015-03-14T04:45:00.000-04:00', 11932.086],
    ['2015-03-14T04:50:00.000-04:00', 11989.847],
    ['2015-03-14T04:55:00.000-04:00', 12000.971],
]
```

---

**Edit**: per discussion in comments, what about:

```
import itertools, pprint

def avg(gf):
    _sum = 0
    for (i,e) in enumerate(gf): _sum += e
    return float(_sum) / (i+1)

d = {}
for (key,gen) in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda l: int(l[0][11:13])):
    vals = list(gen)                    # Unpack generator
    key = vals[0][0][:13]
    d[key] = avg(v for (d,v) in vals)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

Comment: My reading was that the OP wanted the *average* value in an hour, not the sum, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @jedwards I am sorry but I am quite new at this.   Is this assuming I already have a dictionary?

Comment: @Alex, no, it assumes you have a list (named `lst`) comprised of 2-element sublists as elements.

Comment: @jedwards  This worked like a charm.  Thank you!  Should I read on  itertools.groupby to learn more on how you did this?

Comment: @Alex, sure, and if you have any questions feel feel free to post them as comments to the answer and I'll try to explain (or if they're big enough, their own question :)

Comment: One quick change.  What if I not always 12 entries for each hour.  Can I check for minutes 00-55 for each hour?  That way, if minute 10 is missing, I get the average of 11 items.  Let me know if this is a new question and I'll be glad to do a new posting.  Thanks!

Comment: Using this approach as long as the hour is the same, it doesn't matter what the minute is.  All minutes for a given hour will be grouped into the same group.  So whether that's one entry or 100, they'll be grouped up and averaged.

Comment: How can I include the hour in my final output. Something like this 00 148410.565, 01 147042.743 knowing that their is possibility of not having a hour reading.

Comment: @Alex, if you use the code in my answer (minus the last line with `pprint`), you can loop through the 24 hour day with something like `for i in range(24): print("%2d: %s" % (i, d.get(i, "---")))`  -- If the dictionary `d` that was created has an entry for that hour, it will be displayed.  If it does not, then "---" will be printed for that hour.

Comment: @jedwards  Your help has been crucial in the development of my project.  Thank you for your time and willingness to help!

Comment: @Alex no problem, happy to help people interested in learning about the language :)

Comment: @jedwards How can I get the date and hour for the average I just got. Example Output: 2015-03-14T00  148410.565

Comment: @Alex could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @jedwards The current output is the average for each hours and it's displayed as such for hour zero 0: 148410.565.  Could it be change to 2015-03-14T00 148410.565.

Comment: @Alex I added an edit at the bottom of my answer, does that work for you?

Comment: @jedwards That works but it give me the list unsorted.  Can I sort by date if I do this: d.sort()?

Comment: @Alex the problem is, a standard dictionary (`dict`) doesn't preserve insertion order -- if you add `from collections import OrderedDict` at the top with your imports, then change `d={}` to `d=OrderedDict()`, when you read the dictionary keys/values, they'll be ordered (because they were inserted in order).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily using a variety of tools, but I'll use a simple loop for simplicity sake:

```
>>> with open("listfile.txt", "r") as e:
>>>     list_ =  e.read().splitlines()
>>>     list_ = list_[1:]                   # Grab all but the first line
>>>
>>> dateValue = dict()
>>> for row in list_:
>>>     date, value - row.split()
>>>     if ":00:" in date:
>>>         # Start new value
>>>         amount = int(value)
>>>
>>>     elif ":55:" in date:
>>>         # End new value
>>>         date = date.split(':')          # Grab only date and hour info
>>>         dateValue[date] = amount / 12.  # Returns a float, remove the period to return an integer
>>>         del amount                      # Just in case the data isn't uniform, so it raises an error
>>>
>>>     else:
>>>         date += int(value)
```

If you want to export it to lists, just do:

```
>>> listDate = list()
>>> listAmount = list()
>>> for k in sorted(dateValue.keys() ):
>>>     v = dateValue.get(k)
>>>
>>>     listDate.append(k)
>>>     listAmount.append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty way

```
reads= [
'2015-03-14T00:00:00.000-04:00 12545.869',
'2015-03-14T00:05:00.000-04:00 12467.326',
'2015-03-14T00:10:00.000-04:00 12416.948',
'2015-03-14T00:15:00.000-04:00 12315.698',
'2015-03-14T00:20:00.000-04:00 12276.38',
'2015-03-14T00:25:00.000-04:00 12498.696',
'2015-03-14T00:30:00.000-04:00 12426.145',
'2015-03-14T00:35:00.000-04:00 12368.659',
'2015-03-14T00:40:00.000-04:00 12322.785',
'2015-03-14T00:45:00.000-04:00 12292.719',
'2015-03-14T00:50:00.000-04:00 12257.965',
'2015-03-14T00:55:00.000-04:00 12221.375',
'2015-03-14T01:00:00.000-04:00 12393.725',
'2015-03-14T01:05:00.000-04:00 12366.674',
'2015-03-14T01:10:00.000-04:00 12378.578',
'2015-03-14T01:15:00.000-04:00 12340.754',
'2015-03-14T01:20:00.000-04:00 12288.511',
'2015-03-14T01:25:00.000-04:00 12266.136',
'2015-03-14T01:30:00.000-04:00 12236.639',
'2015-03-14T01:35:00.000-04:00 12181.668',
'2015-03-14T01:40:00.000-04:00 12171.992',
'2015-03-14T01:45:00.000-04:00 12164.298',
'2015-03-14T01:50:00.000-04:00 12137.282',
'2015-03-14T01:55:00.000-04:00 12116.486'
]

sums = {}

for read in reads:
    hour = read.split(':')[0]
    value = float(read.split().pop())
    if hour in sums:
        sums[hour] += value
    else:
        sums[hour] = value


avg = {}
for s in sums:
    avg[s] = sums[s]/12

print avg
```